# Google Analytics custom report shows zero pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I've created a custom report with dimensions:

```
Event Category, Event Label, Page Title
```

And want to see this metrics:

```
Total Events
Pageviews
Avg. Time on Page
```

Also, I applied a filter by event category.

I see my report with some values in **Total Events** column, but **Pageviews** and **Avg. Time on Page** are always zero. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is occuring due to the custom report you have generated.

Events by definition are not page views. This means that an Event dimension (category, action, label) cant have page view metrics such as pageviews or average time on page, because that information does not relate to the specific event.

One way to product the report you might want is to create a segment for sessions which contain the event you are interested in, then create a Custom Report with the dimension pages, total event, pageviews, and time on page.

Update:

Understanding what you are trying to achieve, you will need to do two reports, and merge them on pagePath (assuming there is only one video per page).

Report 1:
Event Category, Event Label, Page Path, Total Events.

```
Event Category  Event Label  Page Path  Total Events
Video           Id1          /video1     2
Video           Id2          /video2     3
```

Report 2: Page Path, Page Views, Time on Page

Report two requires a segment: Sessions that contain Event Category == VideoView (assumed category).

Page Path, Page View, Average Time on Page.

```
Page Path    Page views   Average Time on page
/video1      5            0:42
/video1      10           0:16
```

The final merged dataset would look like

```
Event Category  Event Label  Page Path  Total Events  Page views  Average Time on page
Video           Id1          /video1     2            5           0:42
Video           Id2          /video2     3            10          0:16
```

Comment: Thx. I created a segment (by session include my event), and applied my custom report to the segment and again values of "Pageviews"
"Avg. Time on Page" are 0 and 0:00:00.

Comment: Again, if you have Event Category/Action/Label as a dimension, you will not be able to retrieve page related metrics.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. I'l try to explain my problem. I inline videos on my website pages. When visitor clicks on it, i send an GA event with video id as event label. In the report i want to see: 1. Website page. 2. Video id. 3. Clicks. 4. Page views. 5. Average time on page. Any way to do this?

Comment: Thx! I got 2 reports, but how can i merge it? And if it matters, I have several videos on some pages.

Comment: If you have multiple videos on a single page then you will need to refine your segment to select the activity per page. To merge the different tables you need to use a databasing software like SQL or Python

Comment: And no way to make a report by GA custom reports service?

Comment: No, Google Analytics does not have that sort of in built functionality. It is more of a data collection platform with some pre-aggregated tables, rather then an analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as [sdhaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638747/sdhaus) says you'd need to merge two reports. I didn't want to include even more vendors but I found nowadays Looker Studio does exactly that: you can just merge the Analytics data source with another instance of itself and voila: match on page title or path and you're done!